# Automatically downloading pdf from WCF REST service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, download

I have a WCF REST service that gets an id from the client side and then downloads a file. I seem to be getting the file returning in the body of my response but it is not automatically downloading it.

I have never attempted doing this before, so i was wondering if someone would be able to help with some guidance. I am returning a Stream back to the client side.

Here is my `OperationContract`:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/GetFile/{id}")]
Stream GetFile(string id);
```

Here is my `GetFile` method:

```
public Stream GetFile(string BillingPeriodId)
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\pdf-test.pdf");
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;inline; filename=pdf-test.pdf");
    return new MemoryStream(bytes);
}
```

Again, my service seems to be returning with a `200`. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you have **ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json** in the WebInvoke attribute if you intend to return a stream?

Comment: @fanuc_bob - old code... I have removed it since then, but that was not my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT return the Memory Stream from your service. Even it is looks good and it is well compiled, it is not working. Return a Stream object from your service.

Your code can look like this :

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetFile/{BillingPeriodId}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Stream GetFile(string BillingPeriodId)
{
  WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;inline; filename=pdf-test.pdf");
  Stream stream  = File.OpenRead(@"C:\pdf-test.pdf");   
  return stream;
}
```